# Is ProcessorArchitecture a part of Assembly's Identity?

Tags: .net, .net-assembly

As per MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.aspx) - An assembly's identity consists of the following: Simple name, Version number, Cryptographic key pair and Supported culture.

However, while adding assemblies to GAC, the ProcessorArchitecture is also used to uniquely identify the assembly. Does the .NET framework treat ProcessorArchitecture as part of assembly identity?

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question - you say what an assembly identity consists of and then ask about something that it doesn't consist of.

Comment: I would think this is not related to the identity - it is something that the OS needs in order to know the architecture that it needs to load an assembly as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a version-specific reference to an assembly, the reference includes the architecture:

```
<Reference Include="SomeAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=x86">
```

Where x86 could also be MSIL (anyCPU), x64 etc.

But, when trying to resolve the assembly - the runtime won't insist on the architecture defined - it will only prefer it. That is, if the reference is to an x86 assembly but the present DLL file is AnyCPU - the runtime will use the DLL found (and the same for a reference to AnyCPU assembly when an x86 DLL file is present).

(I've tested this on privately deployed assemblies, but I assume the probing process for shared assemblies - that is, GAC'd assemblies - works pretty much the same).
(This of course won't violate the limitation of not loading x86 assemblies into x64 processes and vice-versa).